# Variable variable assignment error -"command not found"

Tags: bash

When I run the script I get the following errors. What am I doing wrong here please? Any help appreciated- Bash Newbie

Error:

```
line 12: 0=1: command not found
line 13: 0=1: command not found
```

My Script:

```
count_raw=0
avg_raw=0

$count_raw=1
$avg_raw=1

echo "count_raw=$count_raw"
echo "avg_raw=$avg_raw"
```

Comment: remove the dollar before `count_raw` and `avg_raw`

Comment: That fixed it thanks-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=` is an assignment operator when found free and `$` holds value (not only in USA but in bash too) of a variable.

So when you say: `$var=1`, you're essentially trying to type a random string (`0=1` in your case) in bash and bash doesn't like that. Look at the one-liner below that shows one example where you'd type in `$var=1` and bash would be able to process it:

```
var=1; if [[ $var=1 ]]; then printf "Congrats! You have learned the difference between variable assignment and variable comparison in the ${var}st attempt.\n"; fi;
```

Comment: Very good, amusing and also answered the question to a T. Thanks Donbhupi